# Error loading Teams app in microsoft365.com (errorCode: 5600, "AppID is not valid. Must be GUID format")

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

We have 3 different published apps on Microsoft Teams. They're technically nearly identical apps, just with different market targets, so their manifests are 99% the same, other than IDs. They all work fine when loaded in Teams, Outlook and other hosts. But when we load them in https://microsoft365.com, one of them work, and the other two fail to load completely. In the console there's this error message:

> Uncaught (in promise)  Object { errorCode: 5600, message: "AppID is
> not valid. Must be GUID format" }

However, the AppID is a 100% valid GUID.

Does anyone have a hint on what to look for?